# How to prevent SignalR client reconnection after ajax-post request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I use SignalR for real-time aspnet-application. User should upload file through the form.

I use JQuery code for uploading - it sends ajax post-request to the controller method:

```
<form id="uploader">
    <label>Upload file:</label>
    <input name="file" id="fileInput" type="file" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload and check" id="check" />
</form>
```

```
$("#check").click(function () {
        $("#uploader").ajaxSubmit({ url: '/Home/UploadAjax', type: 'post' });
    })
```

```
public void UploadAjax()
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i]; 
                int fileSize = file.ContentLength;
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string mimeType = file.ContentType;
                System.IO.Stream fileContent = file.InputStream;

                file.SaveAs($@"{userFolderPath}\{fileName}"); 
                Temp.certPath = $@"{userFolderPath}\{fileName}";
            }

        }
```

But after UploadAjax()-method ends the signalR reconnects to the server. Why does it happend and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in input type. `submit` causes page refresh.
Changing to `button` solves the problem:

```
<input type="button" value="Upload and check" id="check" />
```